# Running .net applications on a protected network

Tags: vb.net, networking

I have seen that unsigned .net applications will not run on most college networks and as part of a school applications i am trying to let these applications run on a protected network. the app is writen in VB 2008 and is signed strongly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what constitutes a "network".  Are you talking about executing .NET applications on a Windows/NFS share?  Is it just many computers on the same ethernet network?

Otherwise your question is not specific enough to have an answer.